# Apache 2.2 include common data

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have a set of sites co-hosted in one of our development servers.

I need to configure to ALL of those sites the

```
Allow from
```

directive. 
Since this is about dynamic IPs, that change relatively frequently, I need to setup a way in order to easily modify them.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName dbhost.domain
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/dbhost
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.php4

    SSLEngine On

    <Directory /srv/www/dbhost>
            order deny,allow
            allow from 192.168.0.0/16 <subnet1> <subnet2> <subnet3> <etc...>
            deny from all
            AllowOverride None

            AuthType Digest
            AuthDigestAlgorithm MD5
            AuthName "devs"
            AuthDigestDomain /
            AuthDigestDomain /
            AuthDigestProvider file
            AuthUserFile <pwdfile>
            Require valid-user
    <Directory>
```

So, I want to include that "order/allow" in an external file, so I will be able to to easily use it to all configuration files and change it just once.

So, I created a new file that had the following lines:

```
 order deny,allow
 allow from 192.168.0.0/16 <subnet1> <subnet2> <subnet3> <etc...>
 deny from all
```

And then, I modified the  directive as:

```
    <Directory /srv/www/dbhost>
            Include /fullpath/to/acl.conf
            AllowOverride None
```

However, apachectl -t reported errors:

```
apache2ctl -t
Syntax error on line 1 of /fullpath/to/acl.conf:
order not allowed here
```

So, is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is OK. It will work like that. 
The problem is probably because your Apache is interpreting this file (acl.conf) as is (not only as included file), because it has .conf extension - you probably have `Include *.conf` somewhere in `httpd.conf` or `apache.conf`.

Change the name of the file to e.g. acl.include and should be OK.